# How can I handle with empty option value for HTTP request in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, http

I am trying to handle HTTP request in Ruby. But, the script is not working.

This is my ruby script

I am hiding the IP information according to my company's security policy.

```
require 'net/http'
url_string = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/review/api?action=search&user=wbt&project=Test'
url = URI.parse(url_string)
response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
  http.get(url.request_uri)
end
puts response.body
```

Actually, our web server request password 'ltoken' option in query.
But I didn't input it because my account don't have any password.

I think that this 'empty query option' is the reason why I cannot get the response.

However, I don't know how I can handle this empty value in query.

for example:

```
url_string = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/review/api?action=search&user=wbt&project=Test&ltoken=""'
```

is not working.

Could you let me know how I can handle the empty necessary query option?

And also let me know whether other problems exists or not in my script, please.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you just need to put nothing at the right hand side of '=':

```
url_string = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/review/api?action=search&user=wbt&project=Test&ltoken='
```